# Как получить ширину скроллбара в js?

Tags: javascript

Нужно каким-то образом определить ширину скроллбара, например 10px или сколько там.

Мой метод возвращает всегда 0

```
var scrollbarWidth = $(document).outerWidth() - $('body').outerWidth();
alert(scrollbarWidth);
```

Как нужно определять размер скроллбара?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По запросу **scrollbar width javascript** находится вот такое решение на **[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript)**

```
function getScrollBarWidth () {
  var inner = document.createElement('p');
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  inner.style.height = "200px";

  var outer = document.createElement('div');
  outer.style.position = "absolute";
  outer.style.top = "0px";
  outer.style.left = "0px";
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "200px";
  outer.style.height = "150px";
  outer.style.overflow = "hidden";
  outer.appendChild (inner);

  document.body.appendChild (outer);
  var w1 = inner.offsetWidth;
  outer.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  var w2 = inner.offsetWidth;
  if (w1 == w2) w2 = outer.clientWidth;

  document.body.removeChild (outer);

  return (w1 - w2);
};
```

Comment: @VenZell, благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function widthScroll(){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
    div.style.width = '50px';
    div.style.height = '50px';
    div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(div);
    return scrollWidth;
}

console.log(widthScroll());
```